# How do I implement a referral module onto my android application?

Tags: android, android-studio, referrals

I want to implement a refer-a-friend kind of functionality onto my application such that every user will have a unique link directing to the apk and the user can share the link via different mediums. I am done with the generating link part, now I wanted to know how to identify the user hitting the link and also check whether or not the app was installed/downloaded. If it was installed, then I need to add some credits onto the link owner's account. And my issue needs to be resolved without the use of API's. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every user you need to have a unique code stored on your server, like `A` has `FOO766`, `A` has `BAR456`.

1. You can use `Google`'s `referrer` feature. In this method, when you `A` shares your app to another user, you need to append a `A`'s unique code with your app's `Play store` link. And when another user installs your app, a `BroadcastReceiver` of your app will be called, containing the code; with which you can verify referral. More info [Google Campaigns](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns).
2. Or you can do it manually. Whenever a user installs your app, ask him for the `referral` code, and you can verify the referral condition's over the server & can determine is it valid or not.

Comment: Option 2 is the way by which I need to get it done, but can I not get it done without asking the user to enter the referral code?

Comment: @SumitShetty Going with option 2, it's a manual process, so yes, the user would have to enter the referral code.

Comment: Got it. If trying to get it done manually then need to increase a step of the user.

Comment: You may use deep links. If user doesn't have an app installed, link would lead to `Google Play`, otherwise it opens your app extracting referral code automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without api.
Create one Label which consist some data.
Now add Scheme for that at your application (Manifest).
After that write code at First screen which get value from that label.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

FYI :

```
<a href="your.custom.scheme://some/UniqueNumber/">Myapp</a>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer!

Comment: I am done with generating links and sharing it via mediums, now I wanted to know how do I identify users those who installed the application from a particular referral link(unique per user)

Comment: Sure.
How you will refer other use ?
With mail ?

Comment: Yes. But, also via other mediums like whatsapp, facebook, etc.

Comment: For per user,You should create unique identification for those user and also need to add track at your end as well.

Comment: Yes, right. But, how to identify user uniquely. IPs do change, IMEI numbers won't work for Wifis. What should I use as a factor of uniqueness for a particular user so that I on click of a link, from my backend I can catch something unique and put onto the link owner's table row and later determine whether or not the app is installed.

Comment: In Facebook app refer SDK.
They generating random number so you can do that way as well.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the solution I need.